# How to attach an image from drawable in MMS in android

Tags: android

I want to make Android apps for sending images using MMS...

```
Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
            mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            mmsIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having

Comment: This code not work, not attach image

Comment: Please explain what behavior you expect and what is actually happening. "this code not work" is not helpful.

Comment: Send MMS but not attach image